# Html - IDM automaticlly download audio sound

Tags: html, download

I developed a simple music website like rainymood.com. But I had a problem that when I open my website in Firefox, my IDM automatically download the audio sound so that I can hear music of website.

```
<audio controls autoplay hidden="true" loop="loop">
    <source src="rainsound.ogg" type="audio/ogg"> 
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

My solution is that turn off option download in Firefox in IDM. However, I would like to know how to resolve this problem by editting that code above to prevent IDM download the audio sound.
Thanks so much !

Answer (score 0):

IDM by default intend to download all media files that supported under FILETYPE Section in IDM.
One solution is you exclude .OGG Extension in idm temporary so you can test whatever you want.
Enjoy

Comment: Why this website (http://rainymood.com) still runs audio sound although IDM downloads that sound ?